# Перенаправление трафика на защищённый айпи Алена

Tags: ubuntu

Вопрос в том как перенаправить весь TCP/UDP трафик с одного айпи адреса на другой. Загвоздка в том что это делается для игрового сервера. И когда я пытался сделать что-то подобное через вайгуард и игрок заходил на сервер, сервер отображал что игрок зашёл с айпи адреса самого прокси, а мне же нужно чтобы сервер так же брал айпи именно игрока зашедшего на сервер. То есть прям полностю все передать. Множество способов перепробовал уже(

Comment: Это невозможно.

Comment: А зачем всё это? Теоретически-то как раз возможно, но требует  нетривиальных настроек обоих серверов и чаще гораздо проще найти другое решение